# sdk 23.02 eumlator doesn't work

Tags: android

I am using sdk version 23.0.2 and adt 23.0.2.1259578. Though I have installed all libraries and I use 
intel x86 HAXM, but still I encounter with slow emulator, which shows only black screen with animated  "Android". I have tried ARM based emulator that also didn't work for me, I have encounter same error

Note- my laptop RAM is 6 GB, and processor is cori5.

now should I use sdk lower version than 23.02 or above

when I was using sdk 21.1 the emulator was working okay

your suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: yes, use real device ...

Comment: which API system image you are using

Comment: @PankajNimgade 
I am using Android 5.0 (API 21 )

Answer (score 0):

@Yusufahmad, emulator's are really slow after api 19 system image sometime they would take a lot of time or may not load at all, better option would be "genymotion" that would help you a lot, or run your code in system image API 18 in ARM, but Intel SYstem image is faster

Comment: @grunk thanks for your reply 
I will try both of them which ever is good I will select it.
But One problem with Genymotion is that, someone has to pay in order to enjoy its facilities.